# difference between clist_map_inline and variable

Tags: latex3

I want to new some commands which have similar syntax. So I used the `clist_map_` command in latex3, but I found that `inline` and `variable` behaved differently. I make a minimal working example.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \NewDocumentCommand:Nnn \NewDocumentCommand
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \NewDocumentCommand:Nnn { cnn }
\clist_new:N \l_cf_diff_clist
\clist_set:Nn \l_cf_diff_clist { x, y, z, t }
% variable
\clist_map_variable:NNn \l_cf_diff_clist \l_tmpa_tl 
  {
    \NewDocumentCommand:cnn { my \l_tmpa_tl } { }
      { \mathrm{\l_tmpa_tl} }
  }
% inline
\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_cf_diff_clist
  {
    \NewDocumentCommand:cnn { your #1 } { }
      { \mathbf{#1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
  $ \myx, \myy, \myt, \yourx, \youry, \yourt $ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

It seems that `\clist_map_variable` won't expand `\l_tmpa_tl` when define the command, but `\clist_map_variable` will expand `#1`. Why would this happen? If I want to use `\clist_map_variable` to define these commands, how should I fix my code?

Comment: You need to use `\NewDocumentCommand:cne`.

Comment: @L.J.R. If I use `cne`, I got an error: ```! Undefined control sequence.\GenericError  ...#4  \errhelp \@err@     ..```

Comment: And add `\exp_not:N` before `\mathrm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `e` variant to expand `\l_tmpa_tl`, and `\exp_not:N` to protect `\mathrm`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \NewDocumentCommand:Nnn \NewDocumentCommand
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \NewDocumentCommand:Nnn { cnn, cne }
\clist_new:N \l_cf_diff_clist
\clist_set:Nn \l_cf_diff_clist { x, y, z, t }
% variable
\clist_map_variable:NNn \l_cf_diff_clist \l_tmpa_tl 
  {
    \NewDocumentCommand:cne { my \l_tmpa_tl } { }
      { \exp_not:N \mathrm { \l_tmpa_tl } }
  }
% inline
\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_cf_diff_clist
  {
    \NewDocumentCommand:cnn { your #1 } { }
      { \mathbf{#1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
  $ \myx, \myy, \myt, \yourx, \youry, \yourt $ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: well, I understand what I should do. but why `#1` can be expanded into `x` , `y`, `z` and `t`, `\l_tmpa_tl` can't? Does it behave by design?

Comment: @Syvshc Yes, by design, #1 is the content of current item.

Comment: Thanks for your reply:)